# Gradients of matrix expression

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, transpose

I trying to find the gradients of the following matrix function
$$F(X,A,B) = X^T(XA+B),$$
where $X,A,B$ are some matrices.
$$\nabla_A F = X^TX \quad ?$$
$$\nabla_B F = X^T \quad ?$$
$$\nabla_X F = 2XA+B \quad ?$$

Is this right? I doubt because of $X^T$.
Would be greatful for clarification.

---

According to Greg's answer. For example:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0.5 \\
2 & 0.1 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$X^TX=\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 2 \\
2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial (X^TXA)}{\partial A_{11}} = X^TX E_{11}= X^TX \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 \\
2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$
So it turns out that the output is also a matrix, not a number.

---

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

Suppose we have $F(X,A) = X^T X A$, where $X,A$ are some matrices (not vectors), and we want to calculate:
$$F(X_0,A_0) + J(X_0,A_0) \begin{bmatrix}
X-X_0 \\
A-A_0 
\end{bmatrix}  = \; ? $$
$$J(X_0,A_0) \begin{bmatrix}
X-X_0 \\
A-A_0 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial F(X_0,A_0)}{\partial X_0} & \dfrac{\partial F(X_0,A_0)}{\partial A_0} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
X-X_0 \\
A-A_0 
\end{bmatrix} =$$
$$=\begin{bmatrix}
T_1 & T_2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
X-X_0 \\
A-A_0 
\end{bmatrix}= T_1 \cdot (X-X_0) + T_2 \cdot (A-A_0)$$
where $T_1,T_2$ are tensors.

1. How to compute this product $T_1 \cdot (X-X_0)$?
2. Will the result be a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\A{A_{ij}}\def\B{B_{ij}}\def\X{X_{ij}}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\f{\phi}\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\E{E_{ij}}
\def\e{\varepsilon_{k}}\def\x{x_{k}}\def\b{b_{k}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\p{\partial}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$The gradient of a matrix with respect to another matrix is a fourth-order tensor, so none of the listed results can be correct since all of them are matrices and not tensors.

Perhaps the simplest approach is to calculate *matrix-valued*
component-wise gradients
$$\eqalign{
F &= X^TXA +X^TB \\
\grad{F}{\A} &= X^TX\E \\
\grad{F}{\B} &= X^T\E \\
\grad{F}{\X} &= \E^TXA + X^T\E A + \E^TB \\
}$$
where $\E$ is the single-entry matrix whose elements are all $0$ except for a $\tt1$ in the $(i,j)$ position.

Simply substitute each occurence of the independent variable with a single-entry matrix in the gradient.

The $\E$ also act as the standard matrix basis, so the full gradient tensor can be constructed by forming elementwise dyadic products $(\star)$ and summing over both indices, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\nabla_AF = \LR{\grad{F}{A}} &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \LR{X^TX\E}\star\E \\
}$$
This is analogous to the way that a matrix can be constructed by summing over the standard basis vectors $(\e)$ and the columns $(a_k)$ of the matrix
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{k=1}^n \;a_k\star\e \\
}$$

### Update

If we replace the matrices $(B,X)$ by vectors $(b,x),\,$ then the basis matrix $\E$ in the gradient gets replaced by the basis vector $\e$

Similarly, replacing the matrices $(A,F)$ by scalars $(\a,\f),\,$ requires the scalar basis (i.e. the number $\o$) in the gradient formula.
$$\eqalign{
\f &= x^Tx\a +x^Tb \\
\grad{\f}{\a} &= x^Tx\o = \|x\|^2 \\
\grad{\f}{\b} &= x^T\e = \x \\
\grad{\f}{\x} &= \e^Tx\a + x^T\e \a + \e^Tb = 2\a\x + \b \\
}$$
Summing the last two results over the $\e$ basis yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\f}{b} &= \sum_{k=1}^n \x\star\e \;=\; x \\
\grad{\f}{x} &= \sum_{k=1}^n \LR{2\a\x\star\e + \b\star\e} \;=\; 2\a x+b \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you. And if we assume that $X$ is a vector?

Comment: Greg, I understand if $X,A,B$ are matrices, then the output will be a tensor.

Comment: @KT7 I updated the answer for the vector case.

Comment: Hello @greg. Many thanks for the update. I do have another additional question and I think there is no need to create another post for it. If you have time, please have a look.

Comment: @KT7 First, if $(A,X,F)$ are $(2\times 2)$ matrices then $J$ is a $(2\times 2\times 4\times 2)$ **tensor** which cannot be represented in standard matrix notation. $\,$  Second, the ordinary dot product is insufficient for such tensor equations, you must use the double-dot product, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
dF &= J:dY, \qquad 
Y = \left[\begin{array}{r}A\\X\end{array}\right] \in {\mathbb R}^{4\times 2} \\
dF_{ij} &= \sum_{k=1}^2\sum_{\ell=1}^2\,J_{ijk\ell}\,Y_{k\ell}  \\
}$$

Comment: @KT7 There's also no reason to create the $Y$ matrix by stacking the $A$ and $X$ matrices since it's conceptually simpler to use the partial derivatives
$$\eqalign{
dF &= J_X:dX + J_A:dA \\ 
}$$ It is also more general, since it allows $A$ and $X$ to be different sizes, e.g. let $X$ be rectangular.

Comment: Hello @greg. Really appreciate your help! I did some calculations and got stuck with dimensions and inner product (double-dot product).
If A(2,2) and X(3,2) matrices then F will be (2,2) having $F = X^T X A$.
$ J $ has the following dim (3,2,2,2) and $X(3,2)$

Comment: but according to your formula for double-dot product the final dimension would be (3,2) 
$$F(2,2)∼J(3,2,2,2)X_0(3,2)$$

Comment: I wanted to say that double-dot product of these tensors assumes contraction with respect to the last two indices of the first tensor and the first two indices of the second tensor. I think i missed something cause last indexes of the 1st tensor do not match with 2nd one.

Comment: @KT7 The component-wise definition of the gradient tensor is $$J_{ijk\ell} = \frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial X_{k\ell}}$$ So its shape is $(i_{max}\times j_{max}\times k_{max}\times \ell_{max}) = (2\times 2\times 3\times 2)$ and this is compatible with the contractions required by the double-dot product. You may have gotten into the bad habit of transposing gradients due to some terrible course notes or textbooks that  are out there. $\;$

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Many thanks to you!